# Why Visual Studio is duplicating existing form with locked components, when I try to create a blank new form on my solution?

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I need to be able to create a blank new form not a copy of an existing one.
I do not want to make my first form components public in order to be able to remove them from my second new form.

Tried to create a second form on my project solution.
When clicking Add new item > Form (Windows Form) it says it will create a blank Windows Form but when I click Add, it creates a duplicate of the first form I created with its components, locked.

Comment: That's very weird. Can you recreate this with a minimal number of controls (/components) as a [mre] and then include the source of your [formName].designer.cs in your question?

Comment: Click on (menu) Project>Add Form (Windows Form) - it is the first entry right under the title "Project" of the menu. It's not "add new item..." below. (Please do a screenshot of this "add new item")